# What does "Types in Union or Concat have members assigned in different order" mean?

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.android

What does the following mean?

> **Types in Union or Concat have members assigned in different order**

I'm trying to concatenate two subclasses and sort them in a list but I get this error. My code looks like this. I'd like an explanation for the error more than anything else but a solution to this would also be appreciated.

```
    public List<InterfaceItem> GetTransactions(string id)
    {
        DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var tollQuery = from t in context.Tolls
                        where t.account_id.Equals(id)
                        select new TollTest { Date = t.status_time, Amount = t.fee, Plate = t.plate_id };
        var paymentQuery = from p in context.Payments
                           where p.account_id.Equals(id)
                           select new PaymentTest { Date = p.status_time, Amount = p.payment1, PaymentMethod = p.credit_type };

        IQueryable<InterfaceItem> toll = tollQuery;
        IQueryable<InterfaceItem> payment = paymentQuery;

        var all = (toll.Concat(payment)).ToList();
        return all;
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing here, but typically when you union the selected fields have to match by type (and should logically as well). I'm guessing (again) plate_id and credit_type are different types? What happens when you (temporarily) change PaymentMethod = 0? Does it work in that case?

Comment: plate_id and credit_type are both strings. TollTest and PaymentTest are both subclasses of InterfaceItem where they inherit Date(DateTime) and Amount(decimal). If I return the List as a subclass it works just fine but I'm not sure about joining the two. I've tried tollQuery.Cast<InterfaceItem>().Union(paymentQuery.Cast<InterfaceItem>()).OrderBy(x => x.Date).ToList(); but that just gives me the same error

Comment: Does InterfaceItem have fields Plate and PaymentMethod? If so, try selecting or casting to that type rather than your specific types? Or, if both fields exist for your child objects, explicitly select that, like new TollTest { Date = t.status_time, Amount = t.fee, Plate = t.plate_id, PaymentMethod=null}

Comment: They don't. I wanted to see if I could do it without resorting to this but it's a good solution and I will probably use it if I can't think of anything else. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With inspiration from Nikki9696 I figured it out. I was using TollTest and PaymentTest as subclasses of InterfaceItem. In the end I removed the subclasses and instead did the following:

```
        var tollQuery = from t in context.Tolls
                        where t.account_id.Equals(id)
                        select new InterfaceItem { Date = t.status_time, Amount = t.fee, PaymentMethod = null,  Plate = t.plate_id };
        var paymentQuery = from p in context.Payments
                           where p.account_id.Equals(id)
                           select new InterfaceItem { Date = p.status_time, Amount = p.payment1, PaymentMethod = p.credit_type, Plate = null };
```

I was able to use the subclasses successfully only if I used the base class variables i.e.

```
            var tollQuery = from t in context.Tolls
                        where t.account_id.Equals(id)
                        select new TollTest { Date = t.status_time, Amount = t.fee};
        var paymentQuery = from p in context.Payments
                           where p.account_id.Equals(id)
                           select new PaymentTest { Date = p.status_time, Amount = p.payment1};
```

Therefore if you encounter this error you should make sure that you have the same variable names and not just their types.